# C# LINQ to XML Object Extraction

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to C# and LINQ. I have the following bit of code to extract from an XML:

```
var objects = from elem in xml
                select new
                {
                   Obj1 = new Obj1((elem.Element("key1")).Value),
                   Obj2 = new Obj2((elem.Element("key2")).Value)
                };
```

The objects is an Enumerable. Is there a way that I can get this as a Tuple where in I can access the Obj1 and Obj2 directly without the need to iterate?

Comment: objects.FirstOrDefault() ?

Comment: Interesting! What would the First do?

Comment: What is `xml` and what is structure of xml you are parsing? How many elements your xml have? Do `key1` and `key2` exist always?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use `objects.First()` or `objects.FirstOrDefault()`. The difference between this two ways is, that `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` if there's no object in the IEnumerable. The call of `First()` will throw an `Exception` if there is no object.